# Azure DevOps Change User Identity

Tags: azure-devops

I was "david.corbin@companyA.com" now I am "boogie.woogie@companyB.com". Both are AAD backed identities.

The goal is to change how I authenticate to Azure DevOps so that I have one consistent history without "fracturing" or "historical user".

I have tried (in a playpen environment) various items, but I always end up with there being two distinct identities.

In the past during migrations, Microsoft Support was able to alter identities, but I am looking for a solution that does not involve opening a bunch of support tickets.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure DevOps Change User Identity

I am afraid there is no such solution that you could resolve this issue by yourself.

If you have already add the new account `boogie.xxxx@companyB.com` in the organization, we could not map that old `david.xxxx@companyA.com` to their Azure AD identities.

That is because it will be treated as a new account and assigned a unique VSID when you add the account account `boogie.xxxx@companyB.com` to organization.

That is also the reason why you always end up with there being two distinct identities.

To resolve this issue, we need to contact the support team to map two account as one in the backend. You could submit the ticket on the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem) if you do not want open a support ticket. Or you could create a technical support ticket from Azure Portal if you have [Azure support plans](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/plans/).

Comment: To confirm... If I have *NOT* added the new identity to the organization in any way, then a support ticket (as per above) would be able to make the switch.....

Comment: @DavidV.Corbin, Yes, in that case, you could map those two accounts by yourself when you switch AAD, please check the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/change-azure-ad-connection?view=azure-devops. Please see point 7.

Comment: @DavidV.Corbin, Note: After adding the new identity to the ORG, deleting it cannot meet the conditions for solving the request by yourself, because the unique VSID has been generated.

Comment: Not changing the org....  The org itself  is owned by Company-Z (their AAD). david.corbin@companyA.com is a guest in their AAD and a member of the Org.... However, *I* no longer use that identity, so I am changing to "boogie.xxxx@companyB.com" (the org is still backed by Company-Z AAD, no change there).... so they will (not yet) add this account as a guest into their AAD and remove/disable my old account...

Since there is no change to AAD tenent for the org, there will be not getting to step 7 and the identification of dicc0onnected users....